# .net page redirect based on screen width based from codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Is there a way that I can do redirect from codebehind based on screen width? Currently, I am using javascript to do something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        if (screen.width <= 699) {
            document.location = "http://blahblahblah.com";
        }
        //-->
</script>
```

The page that is hosting this is under SSL, and all links on the front end need to show https, or else it breaks the security of the page. The url I am attempting to redirect to is NOT under SSL, and I have no ability to change that. If I do the redirect from the codebehind, it won't break security to pass off to an unsecured site. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about to store these values in a session variable? When you call an action on controllers, you can get that stored value.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but not quite seeing how it could actually be executed. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742102/asp-net-c-sharp-get-screen-width-in-pixels

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example from what you want to do:

[Calling a webmethod with jquery in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)

Just add width as a parameter and do what you need.